# How can I use React.useRef() of a component in another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two-component App and Header. In Header, I have two button call instances method of Calendar component in App. How can I pass `calendarRef`into Calendar without parent component, because I can't combine `Header` and `App`. I tried context but I think it's not necessary?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Calendar from "@toast-ui/react-calendar";
import "tui-calendar/dist/tui-calendar.css";
import HeaderComponent from "./Header";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderComponent />
      <Calendar ref={calendarRef} height="100vh" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't declared a `ref` and passed it to `HeaderComponent`, see [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
const App = () => {
  const calendarRef = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(calendarRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderComponent calendarRef={calendarRef} />
      <Calendar ref={calendarRef} height="100vh" />
    </div>
  );
};

// HeaderComponent
function HeaderComponent({ calendarRef }) {
  const handleNext = () => {
    const calendarInstance = calendarRef.current.getInstance();
    calendarInstance.next();
  };
  return ...
}
```

[image: Edit Q-62191456-RefExample]

Comment: My code just a reproduction. In my project, Calendar component and Header component is not at same place like that. How can I do this?

Comment: No one can't guess how your project is structured, we answer what you are asking, try asking a more specific question where you reproduce the structure.

Comment: What is getInstance() or next()? The official API documentation on useRef, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref, does not mention any functions, only the current property.

Comment: Its from the instance its attached too, open the example

Comment: Hi @DennisVash, Thanks but how did you figure out that such methods, getInstance() and next(), are supported for useRef hook? This is the classic example of why us developers need Stack Overflow. You clearly figured out an undocumented set of methods.

Comment: I just logged the ref to see whats its holds, it surely written in the library documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a ref in the App component and pass it on to the HeaderComponent

```
const App = () => {
  let calendarRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeaderComponent calendarRef={calendarRef} />
      <Calendar ref={calendarRef} height="100vh" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

```
function HeaderComponent({ calendarRef }) {
  let handleNext = () => {
    let calendarInstance = calendarRef.current.getInstance();

    calendarInstance.next();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-mcclintock-v9lgw?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Hi Shubham - it looks like this approach may no longer be supported. I came across this having tried something similar in my own app and getting a warning in my app 'Warning: Function components cannot be given refs.' and then undefined when I try to access the ref to a component. I noticed your Codesandbox has a error which looks like it may be similar. Do you know if this approach is maybe no longer supported?